# Laravel & complete Paypal/payment solution

Tags: laravel, paypal, payment-processing

So I'm trying to implement a payment solution for my website and after quite a bit of research, I'm still lacking a complete solution. I'm running Laravel 5.0 and need general shopping cart payment functionality. I thought I would post this to try to create a reference to help others that may be having this issue. I got as far as getting test transactions into the Paypal sandbox and that's where the brick wall has seemed to come in, but a complete overview would be helpful. I’ll list my issues that I need to overcome in order to issues some run into.

**Issues needing to be resolved to complete the payment solution implementation**

- My biggest issue with what I've seen has been receiving the
  notification of successful payment processing back, but I'll walk
  through what I've seen thus far. I'm not sure how to set up a listener or other methods of detecting a correct payment processing
- Dealing with Credit Card information when I’m trying to avoid it
  for the time being – I’d like that to be done on the gateway website
- Potentially kicking off some of the calls to these APIs in Laravel
  when the user checks out
- I’m trying to move items to my server, but the development is being
  done locally which creates an added issue

The options

**There’s simply Paypal**

- I’ve taken the basic form implementation as far as getting payments into Paypal, but I can’t seem to get payments out. I’ve tried the returnURL and that doesn’t seem to work
- I do not necessarily like this option because it seems to be leaving a lot of information in the form that would seem to be better kept private on the server

**I’d like to use something complete on git but I seem to find the documentation incomplete**

- https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal
- --Not sure how to implement this in laravel
- https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay
- --doesn’t appear to be being used
- https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal
- https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment
- --The card information is not intuitive here as that’s what going to
  paypal’s supposed to manage
- It would be nice to use Paypal express but I don’t see a ton of resources specifically for that.

**There's Aimeos.**

- I don't necessarily feel safe with manually implementing the vsrf
  protection and it doesn't seem to offer that much more on the payment
  front than

**I’m open to others that are complete and charge similar fees to Paypal**

- Stripe doesn’t work for me. I’m not doing a basic subscription

Any complete thoughts would be greatly appreciated as documentation left short has caused issues in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PayPal PHP SDK will make all of the PayPal classic API calls very quick and easy for you.  It's available on Packagist/Composer and can be applied to Laravel very easily.

It supports Express Checkout, Payments Pro, Invoicing, Transaction Search, Transaction Details, Refunds, etc.

This is done in Laravel 4, but I had begun this "[PayPal Glass](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass)" project a while back to show how the class library / sdk can essentially replicate everything you can do within a PayPal account.  Here it is [running on my local test server](http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com/).

So yeah, that SDK should be able to handle everything you need to do with PayPal inside a Laravel project.